# Aliexpress blocks any request with proxy

Tags: php, curl

Recently Aliexpress started to block all requests sent through a proxy.

I tried many ways like:

- CURL
- file_get_contents
- tream_get_contents

But all of them got blocked whenever I add proxy and it works normally when I remove it.

```php
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; rv:1.7.3) Gecko/20041001 Firefox/0.10.1");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $main_url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE , 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, "proxy");
```

I also tried to add all kinds of headers.

How can I prevent Aliexpress from known that this is a proxy curl request?

Comment: I think they're blocking connection from the proxies themselves. Find one they didn't blacklist.

Comment: Maybe they block proxy IP?

Comment: I have tried to get new once  and they got block from first request, I will try from different company maybe they are on blocklist  as you said